# Asp.Net Core Disable/Remove specific Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have an Asp.Net Core Razor Pages project, I have implemented a series of razor pages, some of these but at the moment I would like to "disable / remove them" so that they are not usable by users, as a sort of feature flag. Is it possible to do this kind of thing with ex:

```
[Disabled]
public abstract class MyPageModel : PageModel
{ 
    // My code
}
```

attributes or in the Startup.cs or do I have to remove them from the project?
Thanks

Comment: How about an impossible authorization policy? maybe something like `.RequireAssertion( () => false );` and `DisabledAttribute : IAuthorizeData`.

Comment: You could just remove the @page directive so that they are not navigable, but you need to provide more detail about the conditions under which these pages should or should not be accessible for better suggestions.

Comment: I had to disable the pages momentarily so that they were not usable by users. Removing the @page directive solved. A thousand thanks